# Joomla Redirect when Download File not Found

Tags: file, joomla, http-status-code-404

I have a website where customers can download msi files. Over time, I retire older version and drop them from my site.

I've noticed that a number of users are following links to the older file paths. When the do, they're seeing the following:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /files/VBADiff/VBADiff_Professional_Setup_2_0.msi was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I would like to either display my custom 404 message or redirect them to the correct download path. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this - I'm a bit surprised that visitors aren't already seeing my 404 message. Can anyone help?

Edit: I'm using version 1.5.11 of Joomla.

Comment: You need to update your site bad. You are 13 versions behind on 1.5 and all of them are security releases. You are asking for trouble now keeping up to date. It's easy to do and much faster than recovering from a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a redirect plugin for joomla 1.5 which also protocalls 404 accesses. I like this one: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/url-redirection/14676

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll give it a try and mark your answer if it works out for me.

Comment: Odd, but this add in doesn't appear to detect attempts to download a file, only unavailable pages, so it doesn't help I'm afraid.

Comment: If you have links not routing over joomla you should redirect these links via htaccess.
`Redirect 301 old.html new.html`

Answer (score 1):

File downloads, particularly direct links from an outside referrer do not instantiate the Joomla framework so nothing in Joomla is going to help your problem. Depending on the URLs you are using to get to the files, you will have to fix this issue with either a typical 301 redirect for URLs without query strings or mod_rewrite for those with.